# java mail messageheader always null?

Tags: java, email, header, pop3

I'm writing a POP3MailConnector. With the following Code i'm getting the messages from the store:

```
Store store = null;
try {
    store = session.getStore();
    store.connect();

    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
         .
         .
         .
}
```

message.getContent() displays the content of the message, but message.getAllHeaders() returns no values and is always null.

When the message is load with FileInputStream all Headers contain values.
I'm testing with a local James Mailserver and hMailServer.

Does anyone has an idea, while the header is always null, when using folder.getMessages() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of searching, i found the solution. The order of the maven dependencies is important. The java mail dependency must be set at the first position! That's it.